# Can we write an app without using a single line of XML code in android (I mean Only using java)

Tags: android

Can we write an app without using a single line of XML code in android (I mean Only using java)

if so can we remove **setContentView** in onCreate method?

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

can we remove this line of code from java file?

Comment: Yes you can do this and creating your own layout on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can take look at following block of code

```
//lLayout block
        LinearLayout block = new LinearLayout(this);
        block.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams blockParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lTextParams.weight = 1;
        llMain.addView(block, blockParams);

        //lLayout lText
        LinearLayout lText = new LinearLayout(this);
        lText.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(69,0,0,0));
        lText.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.67f);
        lTextParams.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10);
        lTextParams.weight = 1;
        lText.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        block.addView(lText, lTextParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can write all the layout using only JAVA Code, see the example below:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


    TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
    titleView.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    titleView.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    titleView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
    titleView.setText("Hallo Welt!");
    layout.addView(titleView);

    setContentView(layout);

}
```